# How to utilise spare bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth, open-source

Ive got an interesting question for all of you. I'm currently sitting on a 100mbps line, and i would like to use it in some interesting way.

I would like to share it in a way simmiliar to folding@home, SETI@Home, etc.

I have thought of using it as a file sharing server, or a web server, but I'm not keeping it on all the time, only when I'm home. I'm not using file exchange much, because of limited HDD space - all of mine are full with stuff I need.

So **The main question:** How to use spare bandwidth in an interesting and socially usefull way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about providing a TOR node?

http://www.torproject.org

Comment: Thanks for the advice, DONE! This is exactly the kind of advice's I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do not. You ruled out anything which made you interesting - no server always on (pain with DNS), no file storage space.

You could run a TOR node as VPN relayfor people which want anonymity. Pretty much the only thing - bandwidth in and out.

Comment: Maybe there are more of this type of programs?

Answer (score 0):

I keep a BitTorrent client running sharing many different Linux ISOs. (All free stuff, no pirate movies)